# REST Api call on vimeo - Get video played seconds

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, vimeo-api

Iam using **vimeo/player API** in my Angular project I installed it through

```
npm i @vimeo/player.
```

This is for playing video privately(in my website only) and I embeded the url to iframe it plays fine. 
I had written the code for getting events(pause and ended) fired from the player and its working.

The thing I want to do is that to put an API call inside the event (pause) occuring function to **get the video played seconds** and to store in db. And once the user paused the video and closed the browser and after sometime user enters the website again and the video will get played from where the user last paused(get the duration saved in db and continue playing after that duration)(Like youtube).

```
import Player from '@vimeo/player';

export class CoursesComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

@ViewChildren('vidPlayer') vidPlayer;

ngAfterViewInit() {

let player

console.log(this.vidPlayer.length);

player = new Player(this.vidPlayer.first.nativeElement);

player.on('pause', function (paused) {

     console.log('pause', paused);
     //--paused.seconds, the no. of seconds played
     let duration = { duration: paused.seconds, status: false };
     //--the datas are static 
    this.courseService.updateLastPlayed('coursename', 'sec3', 'ch9', duration).subscribe((result) => {     
    console.log("LastPlayed chapter updated");
    }, (err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  });

}}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Or better, your post does not have any question there. Please take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I use [**React Player**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-player) in my ReactJS project.
This 3rd lib supported onProgress callback, which returned **playedSeconds**